# PHP move image in AJAX functionality

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have been triggering AJAX funtctionality and part of my function is

```
private function saveImageOfThePlace()
{
    $image_name = $this->json['order']['image_temp']; // phpBDobOY
    $ext  = $this->json['order']['ext'];              // jpg

    $full_path = 'wp-content/plugins/WindProofCurtainsCalculator/Temp/'.$image_name.'.'.$ext;
    $new_path  = 'wp-content/plugins/WindProofCurtainsCalculator/uploaded_images/'.$image_name.'.'.$ext;

    if ( file_exists($full_path) ) {
        //copy($full_path, $new_path);
        unlink($full_path);
    }

    
  // move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__, 2 )).$this->json['order']['image']);
    return $this;
}
```

I can see everything else is working correctly, but only I am stuck at this part.
I want to move image to another folder and if anyone can help me will be very thankful!

Comment: _HINT:_ `rename("old.txt", "new.txt")` then you dont need the `unlink()` either

Comment: I have tried rename, but unfortunatelly without result

Comment: Maybe link paths are wrong?

Comment: Please provide debugging details for either the `rename` or the posted code (assuming `copy` was uncommented).  `copy` returns a result (true/false) what is the result.  Why delete the original if the copy failed ?  Does `file_exists` return true ?  Does the destination folder exist?

Comment: Thanks will get into debug log

Comment: I found problem, issue was that the code was into folder and that's why PHP cannot get the file, using the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` solve the things. Thanks to everyone for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your code in my localhost. It's working fine and moves file `uploads` to `uploaded_images` directory if the file exists. Also, it will not delete the original if the copy failed.

```
$file_destination = 'wp-content/uploads/007-team-work 1-min.png';
$file_destination_new = 'wp-content/uploads/uploaded_images/007-team-work 1-min.png';
if( file_exists($file_destination) ) {
    if(copy($file_destination, $file_destination_new)) {
        unlink($file_destination);
    }
}
```

Make sure your data is correct, try debugging. Make sure your `$full_path` exist  and `$new_path` folder is exist.